# Arduino USB connection through C#

Tags: c#, arduino, uwp

I am having problems receiving data from my Arduino through USB to a Universal Windows Platform app (UWP). The first code block  is the code running on the Arduino,

```
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.print("This is a sentence that varies...");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
}
```

and the second is for UWP app.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;

namespace SerialTest
{
    public sealed class FMKSerials
    {
        public DataReader dataReader;
        public SerialDevice serialPort;

        public async void InitializeConnection()
        {
            var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(0x2A03, 0x0057);
            var info = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            // Get connection data
            serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(info[0].Id);

            // Configure serial settings
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

            dataReader = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
            while (true)
            {
                await ReadAsync();
            }
        }

        private async Task ReadAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                Task<uint> loadAsyncTask;
                dataReader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.BigEndian;
                dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                uint readBufferLength = 20;

                loadAsyncTask = dataReader.LoadAsync(readBufferLength).AsTask();

                uint ReadAsyncBytes = await loadAsyncTask;

                if (ReadAsyncBytes > 0)
                {
                    string data = dataReader.ReadString(readBufferLength);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(data);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a list of issues:

1. The receiving buffer size is fixed, but the data varies in size.
2. I am experiencing loss of packets in the datastream. (see picture below)

[Debug output from UWP app (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLCdT.png)

Comment: Both look like the same issue. You are **bombarding** your pc with a very large amount of data, so it is possible that data gets lost both at the *Arduino output* side, since *println()* call is actually *asynchronous* and relies on an internal *buffer*, and at the *pc input buffer* side, because by *printing* the incoming data on the *console* you cause a *significant* delay on the running time of your application. Would adding a `delay()` in *Arduino* hurt that much? it isn't likely that the *sensed value* is going to change so much in the matter of some microseconds.. [continues]

Comment: [continues] ..and if it does, then it's likely due to interference/noise. `50` or `100` milliseconds of delay should be more than enough to get enough *data samples* from your sensor, at least in most reasonable applications. *Your mileage might vary, of course.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the baud rate 115200 is too fast to you but it works for me.

However, a higher rate 230400 causes me to get the same issue of yours.

As @Patrick Trentin points out, I insert a delay() in Arduino side like this:

```
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.print("This is a sentence that varies...");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(100);
```

It solves the problem.